# Understanding differences between "apt install" and "dpkg -i"

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, dpkg

I'm a beginner with Ubuntu, trying to understand how package management works, and I have a few questions. This has occurred whilst I have been trying to install CUDA on my machine, so I will use CUDA as an example, but I am keen to learn about this in general terms.

So, following a tutorial, I have downloaded a file called `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb`. Then I have run `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb`. Finally, I have run `sudo apt install cuda`.

My first question is: What is the difference between running `dpkg -i` on a `.deb` file, and running `apt install` on a package name? From what I have read, `apt` uses `dpkg` underneath, so I am confused as to why both would be used in this case.

My second question is: What is telling my apt the meaning of `cuda`? I understand how running `dpkg` on a local file will then install this file, but I don't understand how the name `cuda` is linked with this `.deb` file.

My third question is: Let's say there is a newer version of this package, which comes in a file called `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1_amd64.deb`. What would happen if I were to run `sudo apt upgrade cuda`? Would this remove all files for `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb` and install `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1_amd64.deb`?

Thank you.

Comment: According to `man dpkg`: "dpkg  is  a  tool to install, build, remove and manage Debian packages. *The primary and more user-friendly front-end for dpkg  is  aptitude(1)*". My guess is that the `apt` tool relies on repositories, and  `dpkg` is suited to handle individual (or multiple) packages. But the *wise ones* will have surely a comprehensive answer.

Comment: With `apt` you are sure that any package has complete dependencies (at least from the official repos), but with `dpkg` you can install any package downloaded from x site, not knowing if the dependencies are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg -i <deb_file>` installs a locally stored package.

`apt install cuda` downloads and installs `cuda` package from Ubuntu repositories and PPAs if any are installed.

If you run `sudo apt upgrade`, it will check the repositories for new versions of installed packages and upgrade them.

It looks like the `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb` sets a repository that will be checked for upgrades. You can look into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and see if there is a cuda repository file.

So if you run `apt upgrade` and there is a new version in that repository, it will get an upgrade.

The `cuda` name is taken from that repository.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, would `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1_amd64` be a new version of `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64`? Or are these just two independent packages?

Comment: The main idea is that you don't have to download new packages. It will get upgraes with the system.

Comment: Ok, but what I don't understand is: are these two different packages, or are they two different versions of the same package?

Comment: These are two versions of `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804` package.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if I am sure that I only want an older version, because the newer version is incompatible with something, then should I be sure to only install it with `dpkg -i` rather than `apt install`? Because if I use `apt install`, then any time I run `apt upgrade`, it will upgrade to the newer version, right?

Comment: I am not quite sure that it will be installed without `apt install`. The `repo` package may install only repo.

Answer (score 1):

> My first question is: What is the difference between running dpkg -i
>   on a .deb file, and running apt install on a package name? From what I
>   have read, apt uses dpkg underneath, so I am confused as to why both
>   would be used in this case.

`dpkg` can be used exclusively on local files, while `apt-get` and more recently `apt` are tools designed to be used by the end user, and can be used both on local files and on repository based files. They are built on top of `dpkg`, meaning that they will still call it and use it to install whatever. They are, arguably, more user friendly. There shouldn't be any difference in calling `apt` or `dpkg` on a local .deb file. But only `apt` and `apt-get` can be used on remote files, meaning that they will automatically download and install them. I'm not sure, but apt might also take care of dependencies with local .deb files. It certainly does with repository based packages.

> My second question is: What is telling my apt the meaning of cuda? I
>   understand how running dpkg on a local file will then install this
>   file, but I don't understand how the name cuda is linked with this
>   .deb file.

What is telling apt the meaning of `cuda` are your source files. From what I can tell, `cuda` are not in the default repositories, probably because it is proprietary software. So, if you try `sudo apt install cuda` out of the box it won't work, because it will look for it and won't find anything with this name.

What happens is that some programs, as part of their .deb installation file, add themselves to the sources list. Google chrome does something similar. When you download the google chrome .deb file (and your cuda program) they will, as part of their installation add a line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, so whenever you run `sudo apt update` it will go to the link and download a source from them, and on this source there will be a mention of a package called `cuda` that you can install and be automatically upgraded as `sudo apt upgrade`. It is similar to adding a PPA. Some other programs add themselves to the sources as part of a bash installation script or they might ask you to add them manually. I believe the best reason to do this is ease of updating, as it will be automated as part of your regular updates.

> My third question is: Let's say there is a newer version of this
>   package, which comes in a file called
>   cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1_amd64.deb. What would happen if I were to
>   run sudo apt upgrade cuda? Would this remove all files for
>   cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb and install
>   cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1_amd64.deb?

You should probably ask around the cuda forums for a more authoritative answer on this, and what is the proper process for updating to newer versions. Using the Google Chrome example, it will automatically update to the newer version, so it will remove the old one and keep only the new one. But this is very specific to this cuda package, and how they decided to handle things.

Maybe they use the `cuda` package that they add to the sources solely for dependencies and free software that they can't bundle with their proprietary package, so you would still need to download a new .deb file and install it. Maybe they use it to update everything, and it will automatically download and install the new version when you run the routinely `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Again, very specific to this package, and you should ask on their support channels.